# Using os.system asynchronous, independ from the python process?

Tags: python, asynchronous, process, system

When using `os.system` to open a file, eg: `os.system(r'C:/foo.txt')`, the current Python process, of course, waits until the system-call returns. (ie.: the text-editor closes).
Do I have to use a Thread to make this asynchronous ?

Imagine the following situation:

I'm writing a File-manager for Windows using Python. The user clicks on a file. Now using `os.system(the_path_to_the_file_clicked)` will open the file with the default programm, as set in the registry.
Using a Thread to make the system-call asynchronous would work quite well, but what when the user closes the File-manager ? The Python process would stay alive until the Thread exits, but this isn't this unnecessery ? And on the other hand, terminating the Python-process would terminate the Thread as well, the program closes.

Is there a way to use a system-call to open a new process, independent from the Python-process ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to open a file on windows with the default program, there's a special function that opens it asynchronously and independently of your own program: [os.startfile](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.startfile). This should do what you want.

More generally, for running programs asynchronously, `os.system` can't do it. However, [the subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) can. The subprocess module does nearly everything `os.system` does, plus much more. However, like with os.system, when you use subprocess.Popen, the program is not opened independently of your process -- when your process dies, so does the subprocess.

Comment: +1: `os.system()` is almost never what you want, `subprocess` often is exactly what you want.